# Codeigniter skip login check, define in constructor, for specific action

Tags: codeigniter, constructor, controller

I defined a login check in my controller constructor method like following code:

```
if($this->session->userdata('log_in')== false){ 
    redirect(); //function for redirect to login page
}
```

But I dont want to call this login check for a specific action

(say `public function viewProduct()`)

of the same controller. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify your method name in constructor in if condition like

```
$method = $this->router->fetch_method();
if($this->session->userdata('log_in')== false && $method !== 'viewProduct'){ 
    redirect(); //function for redirect to login page
}
```

Now it will be not checked in `viewProduct` method.

Comment: Sorry, your answer was not posted when I started writing mine. Same answer really only I used segments rather than the router, which amounts to the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. You can either run the login check within the individual controller methods or put the view product into it's own controller that does not do the login check in the constructor.

Thinking about this, I suppose you could check the segments within the constructor like this:

```
if ( ($this->session->userdata('log_in')== false) AND ($this->uri->segment(2, '') != 'view_product') ) 
    redirect(); //function for redirect to login page
}
```

The uri_segment is explained here: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#uri-segments

Not sure this is a great idea though. I would do one of the first two suggestions myself. But that is just a matter of preference.

Hope that helps,

Paul.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to pass through method in controller rather do it on constructor. Constructor first run while loading the controller so handling through that is not a good practice. But certain hooks can work for you but you should really follow the standard practice for future coding.